# Object does not support get_title()

Tags: web-part

I am trying to get my webparts on my page by title, on `get_title()`.

I get the error:

> object does not support `get_Title()`

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(init,'SP.js');
    function init(){
       var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
       var web = clientContext.get_web();
       var theURL = window.location.pathname;
       var oFile = web.getFileByServerRelativeUrl(theURL);
       var limitedWebPartManager = oFile.getLimitedWebPartManager(SP.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.shared);
       var collWebPart = limitedWebPartManager.get_webParts();

      clientContext.load(collWebPart);

      clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
          var Enumerator = collWebPart.getEnumerator();
          while (Enumerator.moveNext()) {        
              var enumTitle = Enumerator.get_current();
              alert(enumTitle.get_title());
          }
      },
      function () {
      });
}
```

Comment: Your code does have syntax error. Did you check it in console?

Comment: @PradipR. yes this, object doesn't support property or method 'get_title

Comment: I think this syntax error, makes so it does not work,  'collWebPart' is undefined

Comment: Did you check weather you are getting the `collWebPart` object in `executeQueryAsync` method in any developer tools?

Comment: No i just found out that i am not getting it?

Comment: this.oWebPart = oWebPartDefinition.get_current(); only having this, displays all webparts in object object but when trying to get the title out of the object i get that is not object not support property or method get_title();

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend try following snippet:

```
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext();
var pageFile = ctx.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl(pageName);
var webPartManager = pageFile.getLimitedWebPartManager(SP.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.shared);
var webPartDefs = webPartManager.get_webParts();
ctx.load(webPartDefs,'Include(WebPart)');
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
  function () {
    for(var i = 0;i < webPartDefs.get_count();i++) {
       var webPartDef = webPartDefs.getItemAtIndex(i);
       var webPart = webPartDef.get_webPart();
       console.log(webPart.get_title());
    }
  },
  function(sender,args){
     console.log(args.get_message());
  }
);
```

Where `pageName` should be the relative url of page, i.e. `/pages/default.aspx`.

Comment: I worked know, thanks, what do u think the problem was with my code?

Comment: I guess the problem might be in iteration of webparts (`var Enumerator = collWebPart.getEnumerator();`).

Comment: Alright thanks, my next step is to check if for example webpart title is mywebpart1 then hide that webpart? Any suggestions?

Comment: I am not sure but you can get the id of the webpart by comparing it to your desired title and then make that webpart hidden with CSS `display: none`.

Comment: Alright, which object should i set to display:none,